# Cloudwatch query dimension

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

Let's assume I have custom namespace in Cloudwatch called nameSP with dimension PodID.
I collect number of connections from each pod. Lets assume that we have two pods so will get two Conn metrics. How can I get from Cloudwatch number of pods ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) to count the metrics, like this:

```
TIME_SERIES(METRIC_COUNT(SEARCH('{nameSP,PodID} MetricName="THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_METRIC_WITH_NUM_OF_CONNECTIONS"', 'Average', 300)))
```

Comment: The problem is that I have no metric with number of connections. It is only dimension.

Comment: You can use any metric coming from pods. This will just count how many pods emitted that metric and give you the pod count.